# whats wrong with my collection_select in my sign up view page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am newbie to rails ,

I am using devise from ryan bates video tutorial , and , i am stuck at one point

I have created user , role relationship

and in the sign up page , i need to provide select option group for existing roles ,

in my sign up view page i am writing

```
<%= collection_select(:user,:roles,Role.find(:all),:id,:name) %>
```

i dont precisely understand collection_select method , kindly help what i might be doing wrong

my models 1 : user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me , :roles

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  def role?(role)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
  end
end
```

my model 2 : role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

my user migration file

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

my role migration file

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

my join table migration file

```
class UsersHaveAndBelongToManyRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :roles_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :role, :user
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :roles_users
  end
end
```

the ERROR COMING is 
**undefined method `each' for "2":String**

2 being the id of the role selected

Comment: Can you add the rest of your view form? Also what is the error that is thrown?

Answer (score 2):

In a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship like you have between `User` and `Role`, there is no `role_id` on the `User` object.

The second parameter of the `collection_select` is the attribute you're updating with the selection(s), in your case it's not `role_id`, it's `role_ids` and seeing as it's a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship you probably want to allow the user to select multiple options, so try something like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:user, :role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name, {}, { selected: @user.role_ids, multiple: true }) %>
```

If you attach it to a `form_for` on your `@user` object you can use:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name, {}, multiple: true) %>
```

Comment: Of course... good answer! However are you sure the selected option is necessary? I think what you specify there, is the default if you don't specify anything.